# Which type of Collection to use for an UNDO features on a webpage

Tags: c#

I'm using Asp.net and C#, I need create and UNDO feature for a webspace.

I would like to know wich Collection is most appropriate.

Array, HashTable, Dictionary?

Comment: I have tried a HashTable, but I found difficult to implement

Comment: Why guys a -1? I think it is legitimate question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you would want to undo the commends in the reverse order of when they were performed a `Stack<T>` would suit your needs. You can then push the commands on the stack when you've performed them and pop them when you wish to undo

Comment: thanks RuneFS for your answer!